# How to install a network printer on powershell?

Tags: windows-7, printer, powershell

I've been trying to install a network printer using Powershell on Windows 7 so that I can automate the setup of our development machines using Puppet.  I found a couple of instructions around but none seem to work in my case.

One of them uses `Add-Printer`, which is only available on Windows 8, and the other ones don't seem to do anything:

```
# First one I tried
PS> $net = New-Object -Com WScript.Network
PS> $net.AddWindowsPrinterConnection('\\server\name')

# Second one:
PS> $printer=[WMIClass]"\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_Printer"
PS> $printer.AddPrinterConnection("\\server\name")
```

Am I missing something?  Or is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
# This function maps printers from an array
function Map-Printers($Printers) {
  # Loop over the array
  foreach ($Printer in $Printers) {
    # Map the printer
    (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection($Printer)
  }
}

# Define a printer array
$Printers = @("\\print-server.domain.tld\printer1", "\\print-server.domain.tld\printer2")

# Call our map printers function and pass in the printers array.
Map-Printers -Printers $Printers
```